# How to use pass DBcontext object to the constructor of an entity inherting GenericRepository<T> abstract class

Tags: c#, design-patterns, entity-framework-4, repository-pattern, webforms

Please help me out, how should I pass `DBContext` object to the constructor of  `MyEntityRepsitory` class?

For example:

```
public interface IRepository<T> where T: class
{   
}

public class Repository<T> : IRepository<T> where T : class
{
    private readonly DbContext _dbContext;

    public Repository(DbContext dbContext)
    {
        _dbContext = dbContext;
    }
}

public interface IMyEntity : IRepository<MyEntity>
{
    MyEntity GetSingle(int Id);
}

public class MyEntityRepository : Repository<MyEntity>, IMyEntity
{
    public MyEntityRepository() : base(mydbContext){}
}
```

I am new to design patterns and implementing repository pattern for my data access layer. I never used Structure map / Unit of Work pattern.

I want to know, how many ways I can create `DbContext` object so that I can pass.

And please explain me the difference of various approaches.

In the above example class named `MyEntityRepository` has a constructor and which passes `dbContext` object to the `Repository` class constructor. Please tell me how to do that.

Many thanks.

Answer (score 3):

**Edit**

As per @Trevor de Koekoek's comment, direct injection of a wrapper owning a `DbContext` can be problematic from a threading and transaction boundary point of view.

In hindsight, injection of a factory is preferable, and used like so:

```
  public ConsumingClass(IRepositoryFactory injectedRepositoryFactory)
```

And then (if holding the reference to the factory)

```
      using (var applesRepository = _injectedRepositoryFactory.CreateRepository<Apples>())
      {
          ... do something with apples
      }
```

or by implementing `IDisposable` on the class.

This gives the client a clean repository, and forces the client to take ownership of the repository instance.

**Original Answer**

As you've suggested, you should configure an IoC container (like StructureMap) to do this for you - classes which need to use an `IRepository<T>` will have an instance injected via either constructor or setter injection. This IMO is the cleanest implementation, as it has testability, the coupling to Repository is via Interface only, and neither Repository nor consuming classes are coupled to the IoC container.

e.g. using Constructor injection:

```
public class ConsumingClass
{
  public ConsumingClass(IRepository<Apples> injectedApplesRepository)
}
```

The mapping of `IRepository` to its concrete class is done via the IoC Bootstrapper (or in config). For improved testability, I would also couple your repository to `IDbContext`, not to `DbContext`, e.g.

```
private void ConfigureIoC()
{
  For<IDbContext>().Use<MyDbContext>();
  For<IRepository<T>>().Use<Repository<T>>();
  // ... etc
}
```

When your consuming class is built up by the IoC, it will recursively detect all dependencies (`IRepository<T>`, and then in turn `IDbContext`) and built these up, and their depedencies etc.

The other alternatives are patterns like [Service Locator Pattern](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Service_locator_pattern) (now often regarded as an anti pattern, as it couples classes to the locator), and [Factory Method](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Factory_method_pattern).

Comment: The problem with this answer is it doesn't address the unit of work pattern.  If IOC is responsible for serving up the DBContext object, then the service layer (or other business unit using the unit of work pattern), will not have a single dbcontext in which to provide a single transaction for the unit of work.